# Regex remove www from URL

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I hope someone can help, this is driving me crazy!

I am attempting to modify Logstash Grok filters to parse a domain name.
Currently the regex is:
`\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)` and correctly separates the domain however, I need to add an additional check to remove `www.`.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(^(?<!www$).*$?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)
```

I can only seem to keep the `www.` part of the domain, and not the domain itself.
Example of what I need to achieve:
`www.stackoverflow.com` should be `stackoverflow.com`.

I need to remove specifically `www.` and not the entire subdomain.

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE

Example inputs to expected outputs (using this post as an example):
In it's current state:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070358/` returns `www.stackoverflow.com`

What I need is for it to return `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Why not capture the domain name without the www part?

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, I need to include subdomains, example: blog.stackoverflow.com but specifically want to drop www. Hence why I tried a lookback. Not sure how to just capture the domain name?

Comment: so you want the subdomain as well, only if it is www you want to drop it? Can you show us possible inputs?

Comment: Maybe you need [`\b(?!www\.)(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/aQ3jU3/1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `(?!www\.)` and `(?!http:\/\/www\.)` negative lookaheads right after the first `\b` to exclude matching `www.` or `http://www.`:

```
\b(?!www\.)(?!http:\/\/www\.)(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(?:\.?|\b)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ3jU3/3)

You may add more negative lookaheads to exclude `https://` or `ftp`/`ftps` links.

*ALTERNATIVE*:

```
\b(?!(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/)(?!www\.)(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(?:\.?|\b)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ3jU3/4)

The `(?!(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/)` and `(?!www\.)` lookaheads will just let you skip the protocol and `www` parts of the URLs.

Comment: That works without 'http/https://' before the domain... Unfortunately most of the domains include it.

Comment: That is not a problem: `\b(?!www\.)(?!http:\/\/www\.)(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(?:\.?|\b)`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Works perfectly!

Comment: I forgot that I am using a lookahead where the pattern can be infinite width. I added a more comprehensive alternative.

Comment: Once again, thank you. The previous worked, however I will change it to the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This will match the part after `www` if the url starts with `www`.

```
(?!www\.)\b(?:(?!-)[0-9A-Za-z]{1,63})(?:\.(?:(?!-)[0-9A-Za-z-]{1,63}))*(\.?|\b)
```

I simplified the rest of your regex too by using a negative look ahead for `-` in the subdomains.